# Log Analytics Workspace Table-Level RBAC and Row-Level Security

Tags: azure, security, logging, analytics

We have a table in Azure Log Analytics that keeps the logs from many different systems.

For example, our `CommonSecurityLog` table has the logs from different Firewalls. I have created a custom RBAC role that allows access to this specific table only but would like to go further and limit the access to specific rows only.

I did some research but can't find a way to do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this natively in Azure - RBAC only supports controlling access at the Table level.

EDIT:
So, as @FidelCasto mentioned, there's also the option of using [Custom Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs). This will be helpful in many cases when you need to collect Custom Windows-related, Application-related. This could be a more user-friendly option but obviously there will be other cases where it will not apply, specially when you have devices sending non-standard logs.

If your requirements are not met by the option above, the only other catch-all option is to put a Log Collector between the firewalls and Azure, and use a script to filter the logs before sending them over via the Log Analytics [(OpInsights) REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api). You could use a PowerShell script to handle this.

1. Each Firewall would send their logs to a local/remote Log Collector.
2. Have a script query/filter through the logs with If/Else based on the Firewall name.
3. For each Firewall, you would create a new `Log-Type` based on the Firewall name. `Log-Type` corresponds to the table name in Log Analytics.
4. Assign permission based on the newly created custom tables.

It's not as straight-forward but gets the job done!

Comment: I think an easier way to do what your are saying would be to use Custom Logs no?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs

Unfortunately, I would really need the logs to be in the CommonSecurityLog table.

Comment: Yes you're right, in some cases. Thanks for the reminder, that totally slipped my mind, I should have mentioned it but when generally when I'm asked about non VM/application log sources, I'll only think of the API. We only used Custom Log once but for the rest of our use cases we had to collect logs from non-standard sources. The output structure didn't match what Log Analytics wanted. I'll update my answer to reflect that but if you face the same issue as I did, REST API is the catch all option.

Comment: Ok in that case unfortunately it cannot be done as Microsoft does not support that yet. I understand that it might make hunting queries very complex if you split CommonSecurityLog into multiple tables! Sorry I couldn't help much!